Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel not working after migrating to PackageReference
yesterday I restructured my files and projects a bit and since I did this I have this new errormessage " Must use PackageReference".
I quickly found out that I have to migrate the packages.config to PackageReferences to solve this problem.
So I did the migration as shown (once with every transitive dependencies checked and once with only the Top-level dependencies).
This worked completely fine for all the projects, instead of "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel". After the migration the reference is bugged and the "new" behavior is hard to explain. In general the reference exists and I can use it in the using section without any problems but, without doing anything I have tons of errors because of whatever reason...
There are several datatypes that can be resolved but the properties for "Rows" and "Cells" are not being found.
I am very curious about this, did I miss something, did the migration miss something? Or might this be a problem with that package?
I am thankful for every helpful response because I cannot carry on right now..

Please show the csproj, code samples and exact error messages.

This problem has been described like so:
"[...]what's happening is when packages.config is used, the Interop assembly is loaded from your machine's GAC. Package Reference doesn't do this for reasons described below. [...]
Workaround is in this comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/987#issuecomment-286307697
Explanation in this comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/987#issuecomment-286307943" by a nuget supporter at github, if you have similar issues just read the workaround
